# If WoooCommerce Product Is In Cart Show Message on Product Page with Cart Count

Tags: woocommerce

I am trying to, based on if one or more product is in the cart, to display a custom DIV-tag with a cart count before the product.

It works, but the count does not work. Why?

**This is my code:**

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_single_product', 'product_count', 1, 1 );
function product_count( $cart ) {

    if ( is_admin() && !defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) return;

    global $product;

    $product_count = $cart->cart_contents_count;

    $product_ids = array( 1708 );

    $in_cart = false;

        foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {

            $product_in_cart = $cart_item['product_id'];

            if ( in_array( $product_in_cart, $product_ids ) ) {

                $in_cart = true;

                break;
        }
    }

    if ( ! $in_cart ) {

            return;

        } else {
    
            echo '<div class="product-count">You have added a total of '.$product_count.' products.</div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: you want to calculate for specific static id? or all product count ?

Comment: Replace `$cart->cart_contents_count;` with `WC()->cart->cart_contents_count;`